# Domain users can't use domain name to access server file shares. Works fine using server IP address & Netbios name

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012, domain, file-sharing

I've set up some simple domain users to test my active directory configuration.

These users have access to several shares on the server.

When I log in using any of these profiles client machine and try interact with the server using the domain name I **can**:

- See all the folders in the servers **root** directory
- Ping the server

I can **not**:

- See any of the contents of the folders in the root directory.  (\my.domain)
- Add anything to the root directory folder.  (\my.domain\shardFolder) I get an error saying the shared directory is missing.

**If I use the server NETBIOS name or ip address I don't have any problems access the server shares.**

**This issue does NOT occur if I log into the domain using the administrator account.**

No errors appear the event log on either the server or the client pc.

I'm confused as to how to troubleshoot this.  I'm not aware of any permission that would limit a user that I have specified as having file share access only when using the domain name but not with the NETBIOS or IP address.

Any ideas would much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is a difficult one to give a straight answer to so I'll just keep editing this to we can resolve your issue.

So what's the basic setup? This sound like a test lab.  So is it one Client, one Server, one DC?

DNS seems to be involved so let's clarify and check a few things

1. Are you using this format to access it: \server.domain.end\share
2. Check that all machines; server, DC, and client are **only** the DNS server of the domain (normally the DC)
3. on the client, perform an `ipconfig /all` it the `Primary Dns Suffix` what you expect?
4. on cmd perform a `nslookup your.domain.name` does this resolve?

Comment: You are correct this is a test lab.  There is one server and one client, and one DC.


yes, I am using:
\\server.domain.end\share and it does not work  However  \\192.168.X.X\share & \\NetBiosName\share both work.

The server is both the DNS and the Domain Controller.  The end goal of this is to deploy in a very small office (5 clients).  Purchasing two servers is not cost effective. 

However, could this possibly be causing the issue?

Comment: I might have mired #2.  The client points exclusively to the server for DNS and the server loops back for DNS.  The DNS is forwarded to Google 8.8.8.8.  I see no other DNS settings anywhere on the client or the server.

Comment: see edits to answer